# Spark withColumn performance

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark

I wrote some code in spark as follows:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("s3n://blah/blah.gz").repartition(200)

val newdf = df.select("KUID", "XFF", "TS","UA").groupBy("KUID", "XFF","UA").agg(max(df("TS")) as "TS" ).filter(!(df("UA")===""))

val dfUdf = udf((z: String) => {
val parser: UserAgentStringParser  = UADetectorServiceFactory.getResourceModuleParser();        
 val readableua = parser.parse(z)
Array(readableua.getName,readableua.getOperatingSystem.getName,readableua.getDeviceCategory.getName)
})

val df1 = newdf.withColumn("useragent", dfUdf(col("UA"))) ---PROBLEM LINE 1

val df2=  df1.map {
case org.apache.spark.sql.Row(col1:String,col2:String,col3:String,col4:String, col5: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => (col1,col2,col3,col4, col5(0), col5(1), col5(2))
}.toDF("KUID", "XFF","UA","TS","browser", "os", "device")

val dataset =df2.dropDuplicates(Seq("KUID")).drop("UA")
val mobile = dataset.filter(dataset("device")=== "Smartphone" || dataset("device") === "Tablet" ).
mobile.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("s3n://blah/blah.csv")
```

Here is a sample of the input data 
                     {"TS":"1461762084","XFF":"85.255.235.31","IP":"10.75.137.217","KUID":"JilBNVgx","UA":"Flixster/1066 CFNetwork/758.3.15 Darwin/15.4.0" }

So in the above code snippet, i am reading a gz file of 2.4GB size. The read is taking 9minutes.The i group by ID and take the max timestamp.However(at PROBLEM LINE 1) the line which adds a column(with Column) is taking 2 hours.This line takes a User Agent and tries to derive OS,Device, Broswer info. Is this the wrong way to do things here.

I am running this on 4 node AWS cluster with r3.4xlarge ( 8 cores and 122Gb memory) with the following configuration

```
--executor-memory 30G --num-executors 9 --executor-cores 5
```

Comment: You are creating a new parser for every row within the UDF : `val parser: UserAgentStringParser  = UADetectorServiceFactory.getResourceModuleParser();`  . It's probably expensive to construct it, you should construct one outside the UDF and use it as a closure.

Comment: @RobertoCongiu It deserves an answer not a comment :)

Comment: @Roberto Congiu Thanks for the quick reply. I get a TaskNot serialisable error and hence had to do this. Do you have any suggestions to  overcome that. Thanks again

Comment: Wrap parser with an object.

Comment: @RobertoCongiu: as suggested by zero323, please add this as an answer. It will be pointer to other users who has similar kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `gzip` is not splittable, and cannot be read in parallel. What happens in the background is that a single process will download the file from the bucket and then it will repartition it to distribute the data across the cluster. Please re-encode the input data to [a splittable format](http://comphadoop.weebly.com/). If the input file  does not change a lot, you could for example consider `bzip2` (because encoding is quite expensive and might take some time).

Answer (score 0):

Update: Picking up answer from Roberto and sticking it here for the benefit of all

You are creating a new parser for every row within the UDF : val parser: UserAgentStringParser = UADetectorServiceFactory.getResourceModuleParser(); . It's probably expensive to construct it, you should construct one outside the UDF and use it as a closure